# jQuery: NewBie Questions, how to call function from another class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function `getCartItems` in cart.js and I want to call that function in another class checkout.js than how can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the script file `cart.js` in your page before you include `checkout.js`. Assuming the function `getCartItems` is declared in the global namespace, that's all you have to do.

However, don't confuse a Javascipt source file for a class. Javascript does not have classes in that sense.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to throw a more complicated answer in here but one thing you can do to help simplify things is to use pseudo namespaces.  Here is an example:

```
// In cart.js
var CartNS = {};
CartNS.getCartItems = function(){
    function text here...
}

// In checkout.js
CartNS.getCartItems();
```

By organizing things into namespaces it can make it easier to deal with scope issues (one of the most difficult concepts in JavaScript) and it makes it a little easier to find things as well.  This is also a way to simulate Classes in JavaScript.  A decent example to get you started is: [3 ways to define a JavaScript class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)